# determining make model and year of a BMX frame

Tags: frames

is there a specific website where I can simply enter the bicycle serial number to determine the make model and year primarily BMX frames

Answer (score 4):

No. Generally, you need to know the manufacturer at least and then see if theres some code for their serial numbers.